# Unit length vectors that sum to zero

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Let's say we have a collection of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$ where $n$ is odd.  Suppose each vector has unit length and that the sum of the vectors is zero.  Is it necessarily true that the vectors will correspond to the vertices of a regular $n$-gon?

Comment: Similar to a bicycle chain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:** Take an equilateral triangle, with centre at the origin, vertices at unit distance from the origin, and one of the vertices at $(1,0)$. Rotate it counterclockwise about the origin a little. We have $3$ vectors whose sum is $0$. Add to this collection the vectors $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

Comment: Ah ok yes that makes sense.  Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. Viewing things geometrically can be useful.

Comment: Follow up question... Call our set of unit vectors $U$ and suppose now that there is no strict subset $V\subset U$ such that the vectors in $V$ sum to 0.  Now it seems to me that the vectors in $U$ must correspond to the vertices of a regular $n$-gon, no?

Comment: Well, that certainly eliminates counterexamples of the type I constructed. But still, I would be surprised if the result were correct, $\sum v_i=0$, even wit $|v_i|=1$ seems like such a weak condition.

Comment: Take a regular pentagon, say with $P_0=(1,0)$, and counterclockwise $P_1$ up to $P_4$. Move the vertices $P_1$ and $P_4$ by a little towards $P_0$, and by the same amount, to new positions $Q_1$ and $Q_4$. That does not change the sum of the $y$-coordinates, but increases the sum of the $x$-coordinates a little. We can compensate for that by moving $P_2$ and $P_3$ "backwards" a little, by the same amount, to new positions $Q_2,Q_3$, again not changing the sum of the $y$-coordinates, but compensating exactly for the change in the sum of the $x$-coordinates. (Cont)

Comment: (Cont) In the new pentagon, no "small" sum is equal to the $0$ vector, but the sum of the vectors is still $0$. One could follow the recipe to build an explicit numerical example. The resulting pentagon still has symmetry across the $x$-axis. I imagine that (though perhaps not with a pentagon) one could destroy the remaining symmetry.

Comment: You are welcome. There are conditions, such as equal angles, that for $n$ odd force regular, but for even $n$ do not. Sum $0$, as illustrated above, is too weak.

Answer (score 1):

$$(1,0),\ (0,1),\ (-\frac12,\frac{\sqrt3}2),\ (-\frac12,-\frac{\sqrt3}2),\ (0,-1)$$